# C calling ASM (YASM x86)

Tags: c, function, assembly, nasm, yasm

I want to call a ASM function in a c code, How do I pass the parameters to the ASM code?

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern int * asm_mod_array(int *ptr,int size);
 int main()
 {
int fren[5]={1,2,3,4,5};

/*Call ASM func*/
int a=asm_mod_array(fren,5);
printf(u,a);
return 0;   
 }
```

now, i want to use this parameters in my ASM function.

```
;asm_mod_array(int ptr,int size)


global asm_mod_array

asm_mod_array:
push r12
mov rdi, 0
mov rsi, 0

mov r12,0
mov rax,0

sumLoop:

add rax, [rdi+r12]
inc r12
cmp r12, rsi
jl sumLoop

mov [rdx], rax
pop r12
ret
```

NOTE: in the ASM code the 0, have to be changed with the parameters passed by c.

Comment: Which operating system are you programming for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the arguments according to the AA64 calling conventions for your platform. On most systems, except Windows, this is defined by the System V AMD64 ABI.

By these calling conventions, `ptr` will be in `rdi` and `size` will be in `rsi`. The return value is placed in `rax`.

See [X86 calling conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#x86-64_calling_conventions).

Comment: Thats what I was seing, I tought I need to place the values on the registers manually, but the complier do it by itself, thanks for the help.

Comment: AA64?  Is that short for AArch64?  I assume you meant to say the x86-64 calling convention?  Or better, "the C calling convention for your platform".

Comment: Yes, AA64 means AMD architecture 64-bit, just like IA32 means Intel architecture 32-bit. These basically mean x86-64 and x86, but a lot of the technical documents refer to to them as IA32 and AA64.